# Resilience4j fallbackMethod issue

Tags: spring-boot, resilience4j

I am using following dependency :

`implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j'`

In my following code :

```
    @Override
@Retry(name = "ingestStockEvent", fallbackMethod = "ingestUnprocessedStockEvent")
public void ingestStockEvent(StoreStockMovementEvent storeStockMovementEvent) {
    try {
        CreateStoreStockMovementRequest createStoreStockMovementRequest = mapEventToCreateRequest(storeStockMovementEvent);
        stockServiceClient.ingestStockEvent(createStoreStockMovementRequest);
    } catch (WebClientResponseException webClientResponseException) {
        if (webClientResponseException.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.CONFLICT) {
            throw new DuplicateEventException(
                String.format(
                    "Skipping persistence for storeStockMovement with eventId {%s} and stockTransactionId {%s} as it already exists",
                    storeStockMovementEvent.eventHeader().id(), storeStockMovementEvent.stockTransaction().stockTransactionId()));
        } else {
            throw webClientResponseException;
        }
    }

}

public void ingestUnprocessedStockEvent(StoreStockMovementEvent storeStockMovementEvent, RuntimeException runtimeException) {
    log.error("ingestion failed {}", storeStockMovementEvent);
    throw new IngestionFailedException(String.format("Failed to ingest event with eventId {%s} and traceId {%s}. Trace:: {%s}",
        storeStockMovementEvent.eventHeader().id(), storeStockMovementEvent.eventHeader().traceId(), runtimeException));
}
```

And following properties :

```
resilience4j:
  retry:
    instances:
      ingestStockEvent:
        maxAttempts: 3
        waitDuration: 10s
        enableExponentialBackoff: true
        exponentialBackoffMultiplier: 1.25
        ignoreExceptions:
          - com.myOrg.commons.exception.DuplicateEventException
```

What I was looking for is when I throw the DuplicateEventException I don't want retry to happen, and at the same time the fallbackMethod not to be executed.

But as per [this discussion](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/804) even in ignoredException case fallback method gets executed.

So, is there any solution for the requirement which I have, where I don't want the ignored exception to execute the fallback method which gets executed in all retried exception case.